# Calculating the gradient of sigmoidal curve at specific point

Tags: r, gradient, derivative, nls

I have used nls to fit a sigmoidal curve to my data to calculate the value of x when y=0.5 - the x values I get look correct. I would also like the gradient at this point, so calculate the derivative as: `grad<-params["scal"]*exp((x-params["xmid"])/params["scal"])/(1+exp((x-params["xmid"])/params["scal"]))^2`
My y values are between 0-1 but I am getting very steep gradient values, up to ~3.5 so is my formula for the derivative incorrect? Visual inspection suggests gradients should be ~0.05.
Full code for fitting model to multiple Species within for loop:

```
results<-data.frame()
#iterate through each Species
Sps<-unique(data$Species)
for (sp in Sps) {
  #subset data for current Species
  subset_data<-filter(data, Species==sp)
  #fit sigmoidal logistic curve for current Species
  model<-nls(Y~SSlogis(X, Asym, xmid, scal), data=subset_data)
  #extract parameters for current Species
  params<-coef(model)
  #calculate x when y=0.5 for current Species
  x_when_y_0.5<-params["xmid"]+params["scal"]*log(0.5/(params["Asym"]-0.5))
  #calculate gradient (derivative) when y=0.5 for current Species
  grad_when_y_0.5<-params["scal"]*exp((bbday-params["xmid"])/params["scal"])/(1+exp((bbday-params["xmid"])/params["scal"]))^2
  #store results in dataframe
  results<-rbind(results, data.frame(Species=sp, X=x_when_y_0.5, Grad=grad_when_y_0.5))
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to draw a sigmoidal curve. If you want to to know if your derivative is correct, please post the equation.

Comment: As a sanity check, you can estimate the derivative manually. Find the x value when y = 0.5 and verify that result, then and a small epsilon to that x, calculate the y value at `x + eps`, and then calculate the slope between `x` and `x + eps`. If `eps` is small, it should be close to the value of the gradient.

Comment: Yes the numbers from my code are nearly 10 times bigger than what it looks like I should getting from looking at the plots and doing some rough change in y/change in x calcs. Have updated with full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SSlogis` (according to its documentation) uses the expression

```
## Logistic curve
Asym/(1+exp((xmid-input)/scal))
```

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=derivative+of+a+%2F+%281+%2B+exp%28%28m+-+x%29+%2F+s%29%29+with+respect+to+x) gives us the derivative with respect to `input` as

```
## Derivative of logistic curve:
Asym * exp((xmid - input) / scal) / (scal * (exp((xmid - input) / scal) + 1)^2)
```

The midpoint of this curve is when `xmid = input`, so `xmid - input = 0` simplifies this expression nicely:

```
## Derivative at midpoint:
Asym * exp(0) / (scal * (exp(0) + 1)^2)

## Derivative at midpoint:
Asym / (4 * scal)
```

So I would suggest

```
grad_at_midpoint = params["Asym"] / 4 / params["scal"]
```

Do note that, unless the fitted value of the asymptote is 1, the midpoint will not correspond to `y = 0.5`. The midpoint will be when `y = params["Asym"] / 2`. The x-value for the midpoint will be `params["xmid"]`.